# Angular NgOnInit executing method before another

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, ngoninit

I have an angular application where I am trying to get an array of sources for an image carousel.
How I have it set up currently I have a "getUrls()" method to get the urls from the database like so

http.service.ts:

```
getUrls() {
    this.http
      .get<string[]>(
        '<DATABASE_LINK>'
      )
      .subscribe((imageUrls: string[]) => {
        this.carouselService.setUrls(imageUrls);
      });
  }
```

That method calls the method "setUrls" to set them into an array stored in a service

carousel.service.ts:

```
  urls: string[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  setUrls(urls: string[] | []) {
    this.urls = urls || [];
    debugger;
  }

  getImages() {
    debugger;
    return this.urls;
  }
```

Then inside of the carousel component I call both of the previous methods in ngOnInit

image-carousel.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpService.getUrls();
    this.images = this.cService.getImages();
  }
```

This would then assign the values set by the "setUrls()" method, but for some reason, it is reaching the "getImages()" method before setting the Urls.

I got it to work by taking the "getImages()" line into a separate method and clicking a button to call it, so that I could make sure that everything worked in the right order and it did, however I want it to do all of that when the components are initialized.

I am sure I am missing something, so anything helps, even if I have to refactor a lot.

I tried to use a ".pipe(tap()" in the "getUrls()" method instead of a subscribe, however it would never call the "setUrls()" method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `getUrls()` performing a asynchronous task which is `http.get`,you have to wait to get images until asynchronous task gets completed.

So one of the possible solution could be,you can return observable from your `http.service.ts` service and inside component `ngOnInit` you can fetch images inside subscription.

**http.service.ts:**

```
getUrls() {
    return this.http
      .get<string[]>(
        '<DATABASE_LINK>'
      )
      .pipe(
         map((imageUrls: string[]) => {
            this.carouselService.setUrls(imageUrls);
         })  
       );
  }
```

**carousel.service.ts:**

```
  urls: string[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  setUrls(urls: string[] | []) {
    this.urls = urls || [];
    debugger;
  }

  getImages() {
    debugger;
    return this.urls;
  }
```

**image-carousel.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpService
        .getUrls()
        .subscribe(
          () => {
             this.images = this.cService.getImages();
          }
        );
  }
```

Comment: So I have this set up but it tells me that I cannot subscribe to getUrls()

Comment: I missed to add return,I edited my answer,please check

Answer (score 1):

Since **getUrls()** perform its work asynchronously, you have no idea when it completes and return **imageUrls**. You'll have to refactor your code a little, like this

```
getUrls():Observable<string[]> {
return this.http
  .get<string[]>(
    '<DATABASE_LINK>'
  );
  }
```

and your ngOnInit method would get updated like this

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.httpService.getUrls()
.subscribe((imageUrls:string[])=>
 {
   this.images = imageUrls;
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

http.service.ts:

```
getUrls() {
    return this.http
      .get<string[]>(
        '<DATABASE_LINK>'
      )
      .pipe(
         map((imageUrls: string[]) => {
            this.carouselService.setUrls(imageUrls);
         })  
       );
  }
```

carousel.service.ts:

```
  urls: string[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  setUrls(urls: string[] | []) {
    this.urls = urls || [];
    debugger;
  }

  getImages() {
    debugger;
    return this.urls;
  }
```

image-carousel.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.httpService
        .getUrls()
        .subscribe(
          () => {
             this.images = this.cService.getImages();
          }
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function in the service *getUrls()* is an asynchronous one. Therefore you have to wait for it to be resolved. You can use the observables for this to achieve. You need to simply subscribe the *getUrls()* and put the get images function call in the subscription block.